# Event Function called before Setter

Tags: jsf, valuechangelistener

I have the following dropdown which list couple of cars, I have it so that it stores the value of selected item in a backbean variable and an event is fired so other dropdowns would fill up according to the selected value of this dropdown control as below:

```
  <Td>
<h:selectOneMenu id="combocarList" 
    value="#{customerBean.selectedcar}"
    styleClass="comboStyle"
    valueChangeListener="#{customerBean.loadothercombos}"
    onchange="document.forms[0].submit()"
    >
    <f:selectItem
        itemLabel="-----------Select--------------"
        itemValue="None" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{customerBean.carsList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
 </Td>
```

Problem is when an item selected from the above dropdown, the event loadothercombos is called before the setter which causes problems.

Note that the backbean customer is defined as:

```
 <managed-bean-name>customerBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.theway.customer</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
```

The behaviour i see in debugging that when i select an item from dropdown:

```
1) Getter is called for selectedcar
2) Loadothercombos is called  <------- This is called by the event
3) Setter is called for selectedcar
```

I cannot get it to call the setter before calling loadothercombos. Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is when an item selected from the above dropdown, the event
>   loadothercombos is called before the setter

Well, is the expected JSF life cycle behavior. Your `valueChangeListener="#{customerBean.loadothercombos}"` is invoked during validation phase after a succesful conversion/validation of the submitted value and only when the submitted value differs from the initial value.  After invoking the valueChangeListener, JSF will continue with conversion/validation of the next UIInput and when JSF implementation determines that the data is valid, then proceed to the next `Update Model Values Phase` invoking your setter method  `value="#{customerBean.selectedcar}"`

Answer (score 8):

Using `valueChangeListener` for this purpose has always been a hacky way. Basically, there are two ways to work around this "problem":

1. Call [`FacesContext#renderResponse()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse%28%29) so that JSF will immediately move to the render response phase and thus the update model values (and invoke action) phase will be skipped:

   ```
   public void loadothercombos(ValueChangeEvent event) {
       selectedcar = (String) event.getNewValue();
       loadOtherCombosBasedOn(selectedcar);
       // ...

       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
   }
   ```
2. Queue the event to invoke action phase so that it does its job after the setter being called:

   ```
   public void loadothercombos(ValueChangeEvent event) {
       if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION) {
           loadOtherCombosBasedOn(selectedcar);
       } else {
           event.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
           event.queue();
       }
   }
   ```

---

If you're using JSF 2.0, then there's a much easier way to handle this with help of `<f:ajax>`:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="combocarList" 
    value="#{customerBean.selectedcar}"
    styleClass="comboStyle">
    <f:selectItem
        itemLabel="-----------Select--------------"
        itemValue="None" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{customerBean.carsList}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{customerBean.loadOtherCombos}" render="otherComboIds" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

with

```
public void loadothercombos() {
    loadOtherCombosBasedOn(selectedcar);
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: a "combobox" is the incorrect term for this dropdown element. A combobox is an **editable** dropdown, it's basically a combination of `<input type="text">` and `<select>`. What you've there just renders alone `<select>` and those are just dropdowns, so call them as such as well.