# h:datatable not populated

Tags: jsf, seam

This is a related (and or follow up) issue to :

[Event Function called before Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722351/event-function-called-before-setter)

So Given i have :

```
<Td>
<h:selectOneMenu id="combocarList" 
value="#{customerBean.selectedcar}"
styleClass="comboStyle"
valueChangeListener="#{customerBean.loadothercombos}"
onchange="document.forms[0].submit()"
>
<f:selectItem
    itemLabel="-----------Select--------------"
    itemValue="None" />
<f:selectItems value="#{customerBean.carsList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
</Td>
```

the event is called when user selects an item from dropdown list and the backbean does the processing to retrieve values of other dropdown list which works ok , BUT i also have a h:datatable which is the problem. The values won't show.

the datatable is defined as:

```
<h:dataTable
    id="calDetails" rowClasses="oddrow,evenrow"
    headerClass="thHeading" var="car"
    value="#{cardetails.allinfo}">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText id="lblCode" value="Code"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{car.code}"></h:inputHidden>
        <h:outputText id="carcodeid"
            value="#{car.code}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText id="lblCode" value="Sold"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{car.sales}"></h:inputHidden>
        <h:outputText id="carsalesid"
            value="#{car.sales}"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

i have setter and getters for `cardetails.allinfo` and i know when `document.forms[0].submit()` is called `cardetails.allinfo` is not null since as i tested it using

```
 <h:outputText value="#{cardetails.allinfo eq null}" />
```

which returned false. I've been starring at it for hours and can't see my fault. would appreciate any input. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the list is just empty. A better debug is

```
<h:outputText value="#{not empty cardetails.allinfo}" />
```

This will show `true` whenever the `allinfo` is not `null` **and** not empty. You could also do

```
<h:outputText value="#{cardetails.allinfo}" />
```

to see all list items in plain text as represented by [`ArrayList#toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString%28%29). If you see `[]` then it's indeed empty. Otherwise if you see `[com.example.Car@1234,com.example.Car@5678]`, then it has 2 `Car` items (assuming that you didn't override its `toString()` method to return a more human readable String representation as many starters do ;) ).

In case of an empty list, you'd need to debug and fix your list loading logic from the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried what you suggested and put `<h:outputText value="#{not empty cardetails.allinfo}" />` which prints true so all good there, as well as `<h:outputText value="#{cardetails.allinfo}"/>` which prints a few of `[com.example.Car@1234,com.example.Car@xxxx]` and i also put in `<h:outputText value="#{not empty cardetails.allinfo[0].code}" />` which print the first code correctly so the ArrayList that containts all the values is good. but when in the `h:datatable` no data is shown!

Comment: I also tried putting `<h:outputText value="#{not empty cardetails.allinfo[0].code}" />` under the first `h:column` removing all other columns to see if that'll show something and nothing still. Any suggestions?

Comment: Even if i put some dummy value like    `<h:dataTable
    id="calDetails" rowClasses="oddrow,evenrow"
    headerClass="thHeading" var="car"
    value="#{cardetails.allinfo}">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText id="lblCode" value="Code"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText id="carcodeid" value="#TESTTTTT"></h:outputText>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>`   i don't see the TEST under the column! :(

Comment: Rightclick page in browser, *View Source*, what do you see in place where you expect the `<table>`? Nothing? Or a table with empty rows and/or cells?

Comment: I recreated the h:datatable and now i'm able to see the values as expected. Thanks for your support BalusC